# How to set fans to 0% on Clevo NP70PNH laptop

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I am using Windows 10 on a [Clevo NP70PNH](https://www.clevo.com.tw/clevo_prodetail.asp?id=1465&lang=en) laptop and Clevo center fan speed settings custom minimum speed is 30%. I want to sleep with my computer on, and 30% of the fan noise is too loud for me.

I am trying to change the settings, so the fans stay on 0% until CPU temperature reaches 60ºc, and only at that temperature would they turn on, even if it was at max power, as long as it is only when the CPU reaches 60ºc I don't mind, I just want to be able to set these limits

But the software is hard locking the custom graphs for these settings as 30% speed minimum even at the minimum CPU temperature of 40ºc, which is enough noise to bother me when I try to sleep.

Comment: It does not appear your system supports your desired configuration.

Comment: [SpeedFan](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) can be regulated to that, but the question is if it works on your computer. I never heard of a computer that needed 30% fan *always*.

Comment: unfortunately, external software like speedfan will conflict with the software you are trying to use (the Clevo Center thingy...), so if are able to use external software, and choose to do so, you would not be able to set the system to increase speeds as it heats up.

Comment: I did try SpeedFan but the fan controls were missing so I assume it doesnt support it

Answer (score 0):

uninstall ur clevo center software then download and install this..

https://github.com/zuyan9/RLECViewer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).